# How to make Swift class conform to Objective-C protocol, without exposing it to Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsobject, bridging-header, language-interoperability

I have a Swift class called `LoginCoordinator` that performs a "Sign In with Apple" request. In order respond to callbacks it conforms to the `ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate`. Because of this requirement, I also need to make this class a subclass of `NSObject`:

```
class LoginCoordinator: NSObject { ... }
extension LoginCoordinator: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate { ... }
```

This class will not be used by any Objective-C classes at all. It is intended to be consumed by other Swift classes (i.e. `LoginViewController`) which will indeed be used by Objective-C classes

The problem is as follows. I eventually import the top-level Swift classes into Objective-C by doing:

```
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"
```

This causes a compile-time error in the generated `MyProject-Swift.h` file that says:

*Cannot find protocol declaration for 'ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate'; did you mean 'UINavigationControllerDelegate'?*

This error appears on the line for the generated Objective-C category that corresponds to the extension that I wrote above in Swift, where I make `LoginCoordinator` conform to `ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate`.

If, before importing `MyProject-Swift.h`, I also import `<AuthenticationServices/AuthenticationServices.h>`, then the error goes away. But I do not want to import this everywhere I import Swift.

If I understand correctly, what is going on is this: when I import my Swift files into Objective-C, it imports all the generated headers in `MyProject-Swift.h`. But one of those category headers (`LoginCoordinator`) references a protocol (`ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate`) that has not been imported, which raises an error.

I noticed that `MyProject-Swift.h` only began to generate code for `LoginCoordinator` once I made it a subclass of `NSObject`. Removing the subclassing removes the generated code, but of course it then cannot conform to the protocol.

Is there a way to make a Swift class a subclass of NSObject and conform to an Objective-C protocol, without exposing it when importing Swift files in Objective-C?

Comment: So the problem is that you don't want to import AuthenticationServices everywhere before MyProject-Swift.h?

Comment: Alternatively you can put LoginCoordinator in separate module and conform to `ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate` privately. You will just need to import that module instead of importing -Swift.h

Comment: @Cy-4AH good idea. Ideally I would like to avoid creating a new module, but if I can't find another way then I will probably go with that.

Comment: The answer worked for me. If it worked for you too, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a private object that actually conforms ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate, and forward message to LoginCoordinator. It's ugly, but can solve the quetion.

```swift
class LoginCoordinator {
    private lazy var authDelegate: LoginCordinatorASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
        LoginCordinatorASAuthorizationControllerDelegate(coordinator: self)
    }
}

//MARK: functions from ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate, but not conforms it
extension LoginCoordinator {
    private func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization....)
}

private class LoginCordinatorASAuthorizationControllerDelegate: NSObject, ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
    weak var coordinator: LoginCoordinator!
    init(coordinator: LoginCoordinator)
}
```

You can also make your LoginCoordinator a nested class which is not able to expose to Objective-C.

```
enum Login {
    class Coordinator: NSObject, ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {...}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add

`#import <AuthenticationServices/AuthenticationServices.h>`

to the Objective-C bridging header which is `MyProject-Swift.h`

Comment: Shouldn't this be the approved answer?

Comment: not working for me